# Merge all array to one array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

i want to merge all array. This is my code:

```
...
$j = array();
    foreach($result as $document)
    {
        $d1 = $document->w;
        $d2 = $w;
        $length = sqrt(pow($d1-$d2, 2));
        $i++;
        echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>$d1 - $d2</td><td>=</td><td>$length</td></tr>";    
        settype($length, "array");  
        print_r($length);
    }...
```

but this is my result (array_merge won't work):

```
Array ( [0] => 38.9944 ) Array ( [0] => 6.1042 ) Array ( [0] => 18.7779 ) Array ( [0] => 11.8349 ) Array ( [0] => 3.2698 ) Array ( [0] => 9.2999 ) Array ( [0] => 7.7512 ) Array ( [0] => 5.4868 ) Array ( [0] => 31.1248 ) Array ( [0] => 6.1896 ) Array ( [0] => 9.2577 ) Array ( [0] => 17.8437 ) Array ( [0] => 10.7357 ) Array ( [0] => 0.8981 ) Array ( [0] => 8.7666 ) Array ( [0] => 2.7877 ) Array ( [0] => 27.7104 ) Array ( [0] => 10.3047 ) Array ( [0] => 19.0708 ) Array ( [0] => 14.5354 ) Array ( [0] => 17.03 ) Array ( [0] => 3.4082 ) Array ( [0] => 22.3757 ) Array ( [0] => 9.7722 ) Array ( [0] => 11.778 ) Array ( [0] => 3.7674 ) Array ( [0] => 15.5889 ) Array ( [0] => 0.6329 ) Array ( [0] => 24.1031 ) Array ( [0] => 10.2158 ) Array ( [0] => 1.5809 ) Array ( [0] => 13.4723 ) Array ( [0] => 4.8482 ) Array ( [0] => 0.989 ) Array ( [0] => 15.974 ) Array ( [0] => 13.8557 ) Array ( [0] => 2.7523 ) Array ( [0] => 26.0451 ) Array ( [0] => 9.049 ) Array ( [0] => 2.6922 ) Array ( [0] => 18.664 ) Array ( [0] => 2.6961 ) Array ( [0] => 0.8077 ) Array ( [0] => 21.3762 ) Array ( [0] => 29.8023 ) Array ( [0] => 11.1632 ) Array ( [0] => 19.1626 ) Array ( [0] => 9.9158 ) Array ( [0] => 5.108 ) Array ( [0] => 12.8582 ) Array ( [0] => 4.3698 ) Array ( [0] => 24.3916 ) Array ( [0] => 18.6804 ) Array ( [0] => 1.9838 ) Array ( [0] => 40.2745 ) Array ( [0] => 10.9428 ) Array ( [0] => 14.5778 ) Array ( [0] => 8.443 ) Array ( [0] => 2.2244 ) Array ( [0] => 3.9861 ) Array ( [0] => 4.2342 ) Array ( [0] => 8.043 ) Array ( [0] => 18.3285 ) Array ( [0] => 13.3765 ) Array ( [0] => 2.0827 ) Array ( [0] => 7.2584 ) Array ( [0] => 3.7701 ) Array ( [0] => 23.3415 ) Array ( [0] => 26.3657 ) Array ( [0] => 25.3173 )
```

What should i do? Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: whats the output of array_merge ? and how are you using it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try array_push function,

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach($result as $document)
{
$d1 = $document->w;
$d2 = $w;
$length = sqrt(pow($d1-$d2, 2));
$i++;
echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>$d1 - $d2</td><td>=</td><td>$length</td></tr>";
array_push($new_arr,$length);
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what it is you're trying to do, then you're on the wrong track (no reason to cast to an array and merge them afterwards - just push values to an array outside the loop).

```
$j = array();
foreach($result as $document)
{
    $d1 = $document->w;
    $d2 = $w;
    $length = sqrt(pow($d1-$d2, 2));
    $i++;
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>$d1 - $d2</td><td>=</td><td>$length</td></tr>";
    $j[] = $length; //No need to cast anything
}
print_r($j);
```

Result:

```
Array (  
    [0] => 38.9944
    [1] => 6.1042  
    [2] => 18.7779  
    [3] => 11.8349  
    [4] => 3.2698  
    ...  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Where have you used array_merge. It's a bit hard to tell of where exactly you are stuck. But if you are trying to create array of $length just use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$final = array()
foreach(){
   $d1 = $document->w;
   $d2 = $w;
   $length = sqrt(pow($d1-$d2, 2));
   array_push($final,$length);
}
```

You will get your desired array in $final array

Answer (score 0):

use function of array : **array_merge($array1, $array2);**

Comment: Don't know how you missed it: `but this is my result (array_merge won't work):`.